# Add count/sub-count to mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I've got a view that is showing the breakdown of all fault categories reported and the area that they've been reported in. What I need to get is a total count of the number of faults of each category, and then a sub count of each area under that type. I've seen around that there are options to use Model.Count(), however whenever I try that it doesn't return the right number.

The view code that I'm using is below:

```
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                @foreach (var catGroup in Model.GroupBy(item => item.job_category))
                {
                    foreach (var itemCat in catGroup.Take(1))
                    {
                        if (itemCat.job_category != null)
                        { 
                            <td>
                                <table id="Tbl_Total_@itemCat.job_category">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => itemCat.job_category)
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>

                                        @foreach (var item in catGroup.GroupBy(item => item.job_area))
                                        {
                                            foreach (var itemArea in item.Take(1))
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => itemArea.job_area)                                                        
                                                    </td>                                                
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get a count per category, and per area under the categories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of element per group calling `Count` extension method. eg, for the category groups you can do this:

```
catGroup.Count()
```

And you can do the same for the areas:

```
item.Count()
```

Comment: So simple when you look at it! Thanks